# Generate random multiplayer Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

i want an algorithm that will help me generate random multiples for given result , for example :

let say i have result = 20500

i also have X = 500, Y= 1250, and Z = 8754

```
the equation is : (X * R1 ) + (Y * R2 ) + ( Z * R3 ) = 20500
```

i need a math equation or algorithm to get r1, r2 and r3, also i need to make sure these random are below certain number.

Comment: If this is for a multiplayer game, the programming language that you are using likely has a random number function.

Comment: Do $R_1, R_2$ and $R_3$ need to be integers, or can they be fractions? Do they have to be positive?